# how to convert list of different shape of arrays to numpy array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a different shape of 3D matrices. Such as:

1. Matrix shape = [5,10,2048]
2. Matrix shape = [5,6,2048]
3. Matrix shape = [5,1,2048]

and so on....

I would like to put them into big matrix, but I am normally getting a shape error (since they have different shape) when I am trying to use numpy.asarray(list_of_matrix) function.

What would be your recommendation to handle such a case?

My implementation was like the following:

```
matrices = []
matrices.append(mat1)
matrices.append(mat2)
matrices.append(mat3)
result_matrix = numpy.asarray(matrices)
```

and having shape error!!

**UPDATE**

I am willing to have a result matrix that is 4D.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want your final giant array looks like ideally? Numpy usually only handles matrices (or submatrices) of same shape. What is the reason that you want to put them together? Why do you want to put them together?

Comment: What is the shape resulting matrix?

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using to combine the matrices? Also how are you trying to combine these matrices? Is this concatenation in 2nd dimension or is it combining them to form a 4D matrix?

Comment: Thank you I updated the question. Result matrix should be 4D.

Comment: To make it 4d, you'll have to pad (or cut) the arrays so they all have the same dimensions - for all 3 dimensions, e.g. (5,10,2048).

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, actually, I thought to do it like the way you mentioned but my concern was that when I need to mean of each matrix with first two axes, then padding can cause changing results. What do you think?

Comment: You might pad with `np.nan`, and use `np.nanmean`.

Comment: That is great, let me try this.

Comment: @hpaulj by the way, can you give me a hint, how can I pad the matrix with nan alongisde with the possible max length of the x within all the matrices, ([n, 5,x,2048])

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain if this would work for you, but it looks as though your matrices only disagree along the 1st axis, so why not concatenate them:

e.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c=np.zeros((5,10,2048))
>>> d=np.zeros((5,6,2048))
>>> e=np.zeros((5,1,2048))
>>> f=np.concatenate((c,d,e),axis=1)
>>> f.shape
(5, 17, 2048)
```

Now, you'd have to keep track of which indices of the 1st axis corresponds to which matrices, but maybe this could work for you?

Comment: Thank you I updated the question. Result matrix should be 4D.